# Targeting multiple elements with one class

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
#bottom p, h3 {
      color: red;
}
```

I just want to make the h3 in the div with class #bottom to be red.  But all my h3 tags are now red across the page.  As this h3 tag is preceeded by the #bottom id should it not just be the h3 tags within this div that change to color red?

Interestingly I have other `<p>` tags in my html and a css code for those `<p>` tags of color white and they are not turned red.

Comment: `#bottom` selects the **ID**, not class. Classes start with a period. And in CSS, a comma separates selectors. I suggest you read up on CSS basics.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing:

```
#bottom p, 
#bottom h3 {
   color: red;
}
```

This would target all the `h3` elements within the node with id `bottom`.

Your `p` tags are working as intended, as your css rule `#bottom p` is already specifying the rule to be applied for `p` tags *inside* the node with id `bottom`.

Comment: And eventually you will be able to use the [`:matches()`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/) pseudo-class from CSS Selectors Level 4 (which will allow you to do `#bottom :matches(p, h3) { color: red; }`).

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like the specification talk about matching pseudo classes.(https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo)

Comment: If you look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ls4tocj/1/) in Firefox, you can see it working. `:-moz-any()` (and `:-webkit-any()`) is the precursor to CSSL4's `:matches()` pseudo-class.